# Why is inequality tested as (!(a==b)) in a lot of C++ standard library code?

Tags: c++

This is the code from the C++ standard library `remove` code. Why is inequality tested as `if (!(*first == val))` instead of `if (*first != val)`?

```
 template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
      ForwardIterator remove (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val)
 {
     ForwardIterator result = first;
     while (first!=last) {
         if (!(*first == val)) {
             *result = *first;
             ++result;
         }
         ++first;
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Comment: @BeyelerStudios is probably correct. It's also common when implementing `operator!=`. Just use the `operator==` implementation: `bool operator!=(const Foo& other) { return !(*this == other); }`

Comment: actually I correct my statement: the references mention *removes all elements **that are equal to** value* so `operator==` is kind of expected to be used here...

Comment: Oh, and there should also be a `const` in the example in my previous comment, but you get the point. (Too late to edit it)

Comment: The reason for this is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35943551/3182664) (that can basically answered with "No, not necessarily"), and the concept of being `EqualityComparable` that Hurkyl mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32863627/3182664).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Because this means the only requirement on T is to implement an `operator==`. You could require T to have an `operator!=` but the general idea here is that you should put as little burden on the user of the template as possible and other templates do need `operator==`.

Comment: template <class T> inline bool operator!=<T a, T b> { return !(a == b); }

Comment: Would there be any scenario where a compiler wouldn't be able to interchange all instances of =! to !(==)? Why would this not already be the default action for the compiler to take?

Comment: @AidanGomez For better or worse you can overload the operators to do whatever you want. It doesn't have to make sense or be consistent.

Comment: `x != y` is not defined to be the same as `!(x == y)`. What if these operators return the parse tree of an embedded DSL?

Comment: @Joshua That breaks badly if attempting to use SFINAE to detect whether `!=` is supported (would incorrectly return true -- even if `operator==` isn't supported!). I'm also worried it will cause some uses of `!=` to become ambiguous.

Comment: @Joshua: name look-up failure, your operator will not be found as soon as another `operator!=` exists in the namespaces of the arguments.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I must have a buggy compiler then.

Comment: @Joshua: Or a buggy test-case, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31b1b71dfb956461

Comment: Buggy test case. I threw everything into the same namespace.

Answer (score 36):

Most functions in STL work only with `operator<` or `operator==`. This requires the user only to implement these two operators (or sometimes at least one of them). For example `std::set` uses `operator<` (more precisely `std::less` which invokes `operator<` by default) and not `operator>` to manage ordering. The `remove` template in your example is a similar case - it uses only `operator==` and not `operator!=` so the `operator!=` doesn't need to be defined.

Comment: Functions do not use `operator<` directly but instead use `std::less`, which in turn defaults to `operator<`.

Comment: Actually, it seems that standard algorithm functions, unlike e.g. `std::set`, indeed do use `operator<` directly. Strange...

Comment: These functions doesn't use `std::equal_to`, they use `operator==` as noted in the question. The situation with `std::less` is similar. Well, maybe `std::set` isn't the best example.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, `std::equal_to` and `std::less` are used as default template parameters where the comparator is taken as parameter. `operator==` and `operator<` are used directly where the type is required to satisfy equality comparable and strict weak ordering respectively, e.g. iterators and random access iterators.

Answer (score 28):

> This is the code from the C++ standard library remove code.

Wrong. It's not *the* C++ standard library `remove` code. It's **one possible internal implementation** of the C++ standard library `remove` function. The C++ standard does not prescribe actual code; it prescibes function prototypes and required behaviours.

In other words: From a strict language point of view, the code you are seeing **does not exist**. It may be from some header file that comes with your compiler's standard-library implementation. Note that the C++ standard does not even require those header *files* to exist. Files are just a convenient way for compiler implementors to meet the requirements for a line like `#include <algorithm>` (i.e. making `std::remove` and other functions available).

> Why is inequality tested as `if (!(*first == val))` instead of `if (*first != val)` ?

Because only `operator==` is required by the function.

When it comes to operator overloading for custom types, the language allows you to do all kinds of weird things. You could very well create a class which has an overloaded `operator==` but no overloaded `operator!=`. Or even worse: You could overload `operator!=` but have it do completely unrelated things.

Consider this example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Example
{
    int i;

    Example() : i(0) {}

    bool operator==(Example const& other) const
    {
        return i == other.i;
    }

    bool operator!=(Example const& other) const
    {
        return i == 5; // weird, but nothing stops you
                       // from doing so
    }

};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Example> v(10);
  // ...
  auto it = std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), Example());
  // ...
}
```

If `std::remove` used `operator!=`, then the result would be quite different.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that it may be possible for both `a==b` and `a!=b` to return false.  While it may not always be clear whether such a situation would be more meaningfully regarded as "equal" or "not-equal", a function which defines equality solely in terms of the "==" operator must regard them as "not-equal", regardless of which behavior would make more sense [if I had my druthers, all types would be expected to make boolean-yielding "==" and "!=" operators behave consistently, but the fact that IEEE-754 mandates broken equality operators would make such expectation difficult].

Comment: "From a strict language point of view, the code you are seeing does not exist." -- when a point of view says something doesn't exist, but you're actually looking at that thing, then the point of view is wrong. In fact the standard doesn't say the code doesn't exist, it merely doesn't say it does exist :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: You can replace the expression "from a strict language point of view" with something like "strictly, on the language level". The point is that the code posted by the OP is not the concern of the language standard.

Comment: @supercat: IEEE-754 does make `==` and `!=` behave consistently, although I've always thought that all six relations should evaluate to `false` when at least one operand is `NaN`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ah, that's right.  It makes the two operators behave in the same broken fashion such that they're consistent with each other, but still manage to violate all the other normal axioms associated with equivalence (e.g. they uphold neither a==a, nor the guarantee that operations performed on equal values will yield equal results).

Comment: @supercat I'm guessing you're thinking of `a == b && 1/a != 1/b`, when `a` and `b` are positive and negative zero? Yeah, that's unfortunate. All of the alternatives I can think of seem worse in at least some cases though.

Comment: @hvd: I would have liked to have seen zero(es) separated out from infinitesimal values (multipy/divide/sqrt result smaller than any finite representable value), in which case one could logically say that a infinitesimal positive value ranks above zero, and an infinitesimal negative value ranks below zero.  1/posTiny would yield posInf, and 1/negTiny would yield negInf, but 1/0 would yield NaN.  As for NaN ?= NaN, I would have specified that a system may have many different NaN values which may compare equal to unequal to each other in system-defined fashion, *but* any NaN must...

Comment: ...compare equal to itself, and the number of NaN values must be bounded and documented (if a system has 65534 NaN values, then a table that holds 65536 distinct values could be guaranteed to hold at least two values other than NaN).

Answer (score 15):

Some good answers here. I just wanted to add a little note.

Like all good libraries, the standard library is designed with (at least) two very important principles in mind:

1. Put the least amount of responsibility on users of your library that you can get away with. Part of this has to do with giving them the least amount of work to do when using your interface. (like defining as few operators as you can get away with). The other part of it has to do with not surprising them or requiring them to check error codes (so keep interfaces consistent and throw exceptions from `<stdexcept>` when things go wrong).
2. Eliminate all *logical redundancy*. All comparisons can be deduced merely from `operator<`, so why demand that users define others? e.g:

   (a > b) is equivalent to (b < a)

   (a >= b) is equivalent to !(a < b)

   (a == b) is equivalent to !((a < b) || (b < a))

   and so on.

   Of course on this note, one might ask why `unordered_map` requires `operator==` (at least by default) rather than `operator<`. The answer is that in a hash table the only comparison we ever require is one for equality. Thus it is more *logically consistent* (i.e. makes more sense to the library user) to require them to to define an equality operator. Requiring an `operator<` would be confusing because it's not immediately obvious why you'd need it.

Comment: Regarding your second point: There are types which can logically be compared for equality even if no logical order exists, or for which establishing an order would be very artificial. For example, red is red and red is not green, but is red inherently less than green?

Comment: Completely agree. One would not store these items in an *ordered container* because there is no logical order. They might more suitably be stored in a unordered container which requires `operator==` (and `hash`).

Comment: *3.* Overload __least__ standard operators as possible. This is another reason that they implemented `!(a==b)`. Because unreflected overloading of operators may easily cause C++ program to get entirely messed up (plus, make the programmer go crazy because debugging his code may become a mission impossible, since finding the *culprit* of a particular bug is resembling an odyssey).

Comment: `!((a < b) || (b < a))` uses one less bool operator, so it's probably faster

Comment: @FilipHaglund in a land without optimisers yes :-) But you're right - your implementation is cleaner and more elegant - and therefore better.

Comment: "(a >= b) is equivalent to (b < a)" - uh... I think you've mixed something up.

Comment: Forgive me, there should be a not in there

Comment: @Random832 fixed. Thank you.

Comment: "(a > b) is equivalent to ((b < a) || !(a < b))" -- It's equivalent to just (b < a).

Comment: One could then ask that is all the operator overloads but < (and possibly ==) are redundant why do they exist at all.

Comment: In reality they don't. In assembly language all comparisons are implemented as a subtract followed by testing carry and zero bits in the flags register. Everything else is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 8):

The `EqualityComparable` concept *only* requires that `operator==` be defined.

Consequently, any function that professes to work with types satisfying `EqualityComparable` *cannot* rely on the existence of `operator!=` for objects of that type. (unless there are additional requirements that imply the existence of `operator!=`).

Answer (score 1):

> The most promising approach is to find a method of determining if
>   operator== can be called for a particular type, and then supporting it
>   only when it is available; in other situations, an exception would be
>   thrown. However, to date there is no known way to detect if an
>   arbitrary operator expression f == g is suitably defined. The best
>   solution known has the following undesirable qualities:
>
> - Fails at compile-time for objects where operator== is not accessible (e.g., because it is private).
> - Fails at compile-time if calling operator== is ambiguous.
> - Appears to be correct if the operator== declaration is correct, even though operator== may not compile.

From Boost FAQ : [source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/function/faq.html)

Knowing that requiring `==` implementation is a **burden**, you never want to create additional burden by requiring `!=` implementation as well.

For me personally it's about **SOLID** (object-oriented design) L part - Liskov substitution principle : “objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program.”. In this case it is the operator **!=** that i can replace with **==** and **boolean inverse** in boolean logic.