# Equality operator overloads: Is (x!=y) == (!(x==y))?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, equals-operator

Does the C++ standard guarantee that `(x!=y)` always has the same truth value as `!(x==y)`?

---

I know there are *many* subtleties involved here: The operators `==` and `!=` may be overloaded. They may be overloaded to have different return types (which only have to be implicitly convertible to `bool`). Even the `!`-operator might be overloaded on the return type. That's why I handwavingly referred to the "truth value" above, but trying to elaborate it further, exploiting the implicit conversion to `bool`, and trying to eliminate possible ambiguities:

```
bool ne = (x!=y);
bool e = (x==y);
bool result = (ne == (!e));
```

**Is `result` guaranteed to be `true` here?**

The C++ standard specifies the equality operators in section 5.10, but mainly seems to define them *syntactically* (and some semantics regarding pointer comparisons). The *concept* of being [EqualityComparable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/EqualityComparable) exists, but there is no dedicated statement about the relationship of its operator `==` to the `!=` operator.

There exist [related documents from C++ working groups](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3950.html), saying that...

> It is vital that equal/unequal [...] behave as boolean negations of each other. After all, the world would make no sense if both operator==() and operator!=() returned false! As such, it is common to implement these operators in terms of each other

However, this only reflects the Common Sense™, and does not *specify* that they have to be implemented like this.

---

<sub>Some background: I'm just trying to write a function that checks whether two values (of unknown type) are equal, and print an error message if this is not the case. I'd like to say that the required concept here is that the types are `EqualityComparable`. But for this, one would still have to write `if (!(x==y)) {…}` and could **not** write `if (x!=y) {…}`, because this would use a different operator, which is not covered with the concept of `EqualityComparable` at all, and which might even be overloaded differently...</sub>

---

I know that the programmer basically *can* do whatever he wants in his custom overloads. I just wondered whether he is really *allowed* to do everything, or whether there are rules imposed by the standard. Maybe one of these subtle statements that suggest that deviating from the usual implementation causes undefined behavior, like the one that [NathanOliver mentioned in a comment, but which seemed to only refer to certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943551/equality-operator-overloads-is-x-y-x-y/35943728?noredirect=1#comment59544090_35943728). For example, the standard **explicitly** states that for *container types*, `a!=b` is equivalent to `!(a==b)` (section 23.2.1, table 95, "Container requirements").

But for general, user-defined types, it currently seems that there are no such requirements. The question is tagged `language-lawyer`, because I hoped for a definite statement/reference, but I know that this may nearly be impossible: While one could point out the section where it said that the operators *have* to be negations of each other, one can hardly prove that none of the ~1500 pages of the standard says something like this...

In doubt, and unless there are further hints, I'll upvote/accept the corresponding answers later, and for now assume that for comparing not-equality for `EqualityComparable` types should be done with `if (!(x==y))` to be on the safe side.

Comment: I guess you are only concerned with built in types as user defined types can do whatever they want.

Comment: Custom type may have different value for the both (due to overloading these operator), but it is bad style.

Comment: TL;DR -- `operator!=` and `operator==` are two different functions left to the developer to implement and there is nothing guaranteeing symetry

Comment: How certain do you want me to be before answering? I don't think that any standard interface requires any custom type to have consistent `==` and `!=` operators. As such the standard makes no guarantees of consistency other than for the types where it defines what `==` and `!=` do and defines them to be consistent. Which of course is a lot of types, but doesn't constrain users. However, I'm not *certain* and it's difficult to do a non-existence search in the standard.

Comment: Does the standard guarantee? No. Do you guarantee?  You should

Comment: Btw you can think of this as analogous to the way that many standard interfaces very carefully use only `<`, so as not to require that `<=`, `>`, `>=` exist and are consistent.

Comment: It could even be sensible. Imagine a class that had some objects that were incomparable. If you compare two objects that incomparable, it is not true that they are equal and it is also not true that they are unequal.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not a C++ expert, but ... wouldn't it then make more sense to simply `delete` the `==` and `!=` operators?

Comment: @Marco13 Then how could you compare the objects that are comparable?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Maybe I misunderstood your application case (now assume that you refered to classes that may "optionally" contain non-comparable objects)

Comment: @Marco13 I am referring to a (single) class of objects that has some (but not all) that are incomparable.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see, likely you meant something like the `NaN` that was also referred to in the answers now. (A side note: All this means that the STL implementations may basically *never* use the `!=` operator *at all*, because it is not covered by any concept - maybe I'll dig through some STL sources to see whether this is actually the case...)

Comment: @Marco13 I guess you're looking for the quote I just added

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Does the C++ standard guarantee that `(x!=y)` always has the same truth value as `!(x==y)`?

No it doesn't. Absolutely nothing stops me from writing:

```
struct Broken {
    bool operator==(const Broken& ) const { return true; }
    bool operator!=(const Broken& ) const { return true; }
};

Broken x, y;
```

That is perfectly well-formed code. Semantically, it's broken (as the name might suggest), but there's certainly nothing wrong from it from a pure C++ code functionality perspective.

The standard also clearly indicates this is okay in [[over.oper]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#7):

> The identities among certain predefined operators applied to basic types (for example, `++a ≡ a+=1`) need not hold for operator functions. Some predefined operators, such as `+=`, require an operand to be an lvalue when applied to basic types; this is not required by operator functions.

In the same vein, nothing in the C++ standard guarantees that `operator<` actually implements a valid Ordering (or that `x<y <==> !(x>=y)`, etc.). Some standard library implementations will actually add instrumentation to attempt to debug this for you in the ordered containers, but that is just a quality of implementation issue and not a standards-compliant-based decision.

---

Library solutions like [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) exist to at least make this a little easier on the programmer's side:

```
struct Fixed : equality_comparable<Fixed> {
    bool operator==(const Fixed&) const;
    // a consistent operator!= is provided for you
};
```

In C++14, `Fixed` is no longer an aggregate with the base class. However, in C++17 it's an aggregate again (by way of [P0017](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0017r1.html)).

---

With the adoption of [P1185](https://wg21.link/p1185) for C++20, the library solution has effectively becomes a language solution - you just have to write this:

```
struct Fixed {
    bool operator==(Fixed const&) const;
};

bool ne(Fixed const& x, Fixed const& y) {
    return x != y;
}
```

The body of `ne()` becomes a valid expression that evaluates as `!x.operator==(y)` -- so you don't have to worry about keeping the two comparison in line nor rely on a library solution to help out.

Comment: What about *If two operands compare equal, the result is true for the == operator and false for the != operator. If two
operands compare unequal, the result is false for the == operator and true for the != operator. Otherwise,
the result of each of the operators is unspecified.* from **[expr.eq]**?

Comment: @NathanOliver That section only related to those types which satisfy "The operands shall have arithmetic,
enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type, or type `std::nullptr_t`."

Comment: @NathanOliver Which version of the standard does this refer to? In 3337, this does not seem to be contained (and I thought this was only an *extended* version of the "actual" standard (which costs $$$, so I don't have it available here))

Comment: @Marco13 That's super old. The latest working draft is [N4567](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf)

Comment: @Marco13 My text was from N3797.

Comment: There is `std::rel_ops` which helps to define operators. Also, operations on NaNs are funny.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot `std::rel_ops` doesn't really work.

Comment: To your point about `operator<`, I've often seen classes that implement only `<` but *not* `>` (or `>=` or `<=`), only because STL sorting algorithms only do a `<` check and never a '>' check.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman So because laziness right? It's not like there's ever a semantic reason why you can write `a < b` but not `a > b`... It's just annoyingly verbose to write out the other three so nobody does.

Comment: @Barry - Basically yes, but sometimes it's more a matter of "There's no semantic meaning to these objects being in a particular order; I just want to make sure that they're processed in the same order every time."  In other words, it doesn't ultimately matter *which* order so long as it's predictable and consistent.

Comment: The link to `[over.oper]/7` is at least *close* to what I've been looking for (although it does not even say *where* these identities *are* defined for basic types). So I'll accept this one for now, assuming that there is no definite statement in the standard, and this *not-statement* means that one should always use `!(x==y)` instead of `x!=y` for custom types.

Comment: @Marco13 Those identities are defined throughout [expr]... e.g. Nathan quotes the one about equality in the first comment here.

Answer (score 13):

In general, I don't think you can rely on it, because it doesn't always make sense for `operator ==` and `operator!=` to *always* correspond, so I don't see how the standard could ever require it.

**For example,** consider the built-in floating point types, like doubles, for which **NaNs** always compare false, so operator== and operator!= can both return false at the same time.  (Edit: Oops, this is wrong; see hvd's comment.)

As a result, if I'm writing a new class with floating point semantics (maybe a really_long_double), I *have* to implement the same behaviour to be consistent with the primitive types, so my `operator==` would have to behave the same and compare two NaNs as false, even though `operator!=` also compares them as false.

This might crop up in other circumstances, too.  For example, if I was writing a class to represent a database nullable value I might run into the same issue, because all comparisons to database NULL are false.  I might choose to implement that logic in my C++ code to have the same semantics as the database.

In practice, though, for your use case, it might not be worth worrying about these edge cases.  Just document that your function compares the objects using `operator== (or operator !=)` and leave it at that.

Comment: You're oversimplifying some with the comparisons to database `NULL`. Most comparisons result in `NULL`, but there are some exceptions. `1 = 1 OR 1 = null` will be true because it reduces to `true OR null`, and true or anything is true in normal rules of logic. The best way to think of `NULL` when working out how databases will treat them is to think of them as "unknown." That doesn't invalidate your point, of course, but it's an important distinction to be aware of.

Comment: "consider the built-in floating point types, like doubles, for which NaNs always compare false" -- Except with `!=`.

Comment: @hvd How could I overlook this? This is embarassing. Even for NaN, they are still negations of each other. I'll temporarily un-accept this for now, maybe someone comes up with a convincing point of why they (really) *cannot* be negations of each other...

Comment: @jpmc26 Technically, true OR NULL is not a comparison to NULL (i.e. it's a logical operation not a comparison operation), which is why the result is not NULL; however, thank you for clarifying

Comment: @hvd Errr... oops.  Thanks for the correction; I've edited my answer to indicate that I was wrong.

Comment: @Steven I was referring to `1 = null` as a comparison.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can write operator overloads for `==` and `!=` that do whatever you wish. It probably would be a bad idea to do so, but the definition of C++ does not constrain those operators to be each other's logical opposites.