# Is there a difference between !(a == b) and a != b

Tags: c#

I have just seen code that used `if(!(a == b))` instead of the more commonly seen `if(a != b)` in C#. I am wondering if there is a difference between the two in C#?

Comment: What kind of difference are you looking for?

Comment: Is your code example the *actual code you saw?*  Because I don't know any developer that would trade `!=` for an additional pair of parentheses unless the actual code is more complex than this.

Comment: Careful with *other languages*, that's really broad.  It's only *sometimes* the same in javascript.

Comment: Use ILSpy to decompile the IL for each instruction.  Do you see a difference?

Comment: The only diference is sanity of engineer who's gonna read if (!(a == b))

Comment: Quite a while ago, I had the same question for C++ - just linking here for comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35943551/3182664 (It's difficult...)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In most cases, they're the same - but they don't *have* to be. `!=` and `==` can be overloaded separately, with different logic. Here's an example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    // All this code is awful. PURELY FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES.
    public static bool operator==(Test lhs, Test rhs) => true;
    public static bool operator!=(Test lhs, Test rhs) => true;        
    public override bool Equals(object other) => true;
    public override int GetHashCode() => 0;

    static void Main()
    {
        Test a = null;
        Test b = null;
        Console.WriteLine(a != b);    // True
        Console.WriteLine(!(a == b)); // False
    }    
}
```

In the *vast* majority of cases, `a != b` and `!(a == b)` will have exactly the same behavior, and `a != b` is almost always clearer. But it's worth being aware that they *can* differ.

It can get even more pathological - `a != b` and `!(a == b)` may even have different types. For example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    // All this code is awful. PURELY FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES.
    public static Test operator==(Test lhs, Test rhs) => new Test();
    public static Test operator!=(Test lhs, Test rhs) => new Test();
    public static string operator!(Test lhs) => "Negated";
    public override string ToString() => "Not negated";

    public override bool Equals(object other) => true;
    public override int GetHashCode() => 0;

    static void Main()
    {
        Test a = null;
        Test b = null;
        Console.WriteLine(a != b);    // "Not negated"
        Console.WriteLine(!(a == b)); // "Negated"
    }    
}
```

Here `a != b` is of type `Test`, but `!(a == b)` is of type `string`. Yes, this is horrible and you're unlikely to run into it in real life - but it's the kind of thing a C# compiler needs to know about.

Comment: This is *really* speculative.

Comment: Beat me by 54 seconds.

Comment: But note worthy as an example of how one could figure out why something is working incorrectly (as in a developer overloaded one but not the other for class/object comparison).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It's intended to indicate that as far as the language is concerned, the two expressions are different. They may behave the same way in almost all cases, but they're not the same thing.

Comment: it's not as speculative as you think.  I've seen == overloaded in more than one case.

Comment: @JohnLord: Sensibly, one would hope.

Comment: custom object comparisons

Comment: @JohnLord: For those, I generally use `Equals()`.  It's not worth it to overload `==` unless you're doing something that's math-worthy, like complex numbers.

Comment: Almost 30 years since I learned OO programming and I still mix up "overloaded" and "overridden". :-) Thanks Jon!

Comment: Even if overloaded, the result of `operator==` must be reversed value of `operator!=`. In other words the two statements in question return the same `bool` value.

Comment: @i486: Could you define "must" here? That's *normally* the case, but my answer gives one example where the operators return `bool` but the condition doesn't hold, and another example where it doesn't even use `bool` anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet How you will use the overloaded operators with `if` if the return value is not `bool` but `Test`? I assume that overloading is with normal logic, not a demonstration of "tricks" and "hacks".

Comment: @i486: You can't, in this case. It's very rare to overload these operators and not return book, but you might want to do so to implement tristate logic, for example. (Think nullable bool but with your own rules.) In those cases you might have an implicit conversion to bool, too. The point is that while in almost all cases the two expressions will do the same thing, they're not guaranteed to.

Answer (score 15):

Sure there's a difference. If `!` and `==` and `!=` are overloaded, then the first calls the first two operators, and the second calls the third. Those are permitted to do very different things, though it would be foolish to do so.

In fact it is common to implement overloaded `==` and `!=` operators in terms of each other; you might say `bool operator !=(C x, C y) => !(x == y);` for example. In that case, `x != y` would be an infinite recursion, which is plainly different than calling `!(x == y)`!

Comment: Who is this Jon Skeet guy? Always muddying the waters. Might have to have a chat with the elders about him.

Answer (score 9):

Logically and conceptually there's no difference, but, since the operators can be overloaded, implementationally there may be a difference.

This highlights a general point in coding though, that any method, operator, property, whatever, should aim to do exactly "what it says on the tin". There should ideally be no surprises, no inconsistent or unexpected behaviour hidden in the implementation.