# Why does bi-directional/forward operators don't support inequality relational operators?

Tags: c++, iterator, operators

I'm currently learning iterator types and there's something that I quite don't understand. First, from what I understood, iterator types are pointer-like types, meaning they can point to any element in a container and can also performs arithmetic operations (like pointers). It also appears that random access iterator type supports inequality relational operators, which I think would mean that we can compare two iterators (whatever that would mean, if someone could shed some light on this). But why can't we do this for forward and bidirectional iterator types ? I mean, the equality operator is well defined for them. By inequality relational operators, I mean the following operators `<=, <, >, >=`.
EDIT: I don't have a concrete example, but I've seen this on [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com)
[image]

Comment: Please clarify where do you see this exactly ? (an example that fails to compile would be even better) it could be that it just looks like the inequality isn't there.

Comment: In the picture you link they are together in same box (?)

Comment: All iterators must support the inequality relation `operator!=`. Do you mean `operator<`, `operator>`, `operator<=`, and `operator>=`, which are only required/guaranteed for random access iterators?

Comment: @Scheff Possibly if you've done `using namespace std::rel_ops;` - but that isn't really recommended since it can affect all types.

Comment: @aschepler Yes sorry, I added it in the post

Comment: @Scheff You're right, just edited it

Comment: FYI: [SO: Why is inequality tested as (!(a==b)) in a lot of C++ standard library code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32849625/7478597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does bi-directional/forward operators don't support inequality relational operators?

> I mean the following operators `<=, <, >, >=`

Because it would not be possible to efficiently<sup>1</sup> implement such operators for all bi-directional/forward iterators.

Consider for example how you would implement such operator for an iterator to a linked list. You'll find that there is no efficient<sup>1</sup> solution.

<sup>1</sup> With constant asymptotic time and space complexity.

> So when comparing two iterators, we're comparing the two elements they're pointing at (i.e. their values) an not their address ?

We are comparing their relative order in the sequence.

Comment: So when comparing two iterators, we're comparing the two elements they're pointing at (i.e. their values) an not their address ?

Answer (score 0):

it does not work because with the operators you compare the pointer and in this kind of memory allocation the memory address of index 0 can be bigger than the one of index 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`a < b` for iterators means if the `a` element is before `b` element in the container. This is easy to check for something that underlying is *contiguous*, ie. supports random accessing. For something that just points to next element, the next element could be placed anywhere in memory for example - hence answering that for any two iterators would require iteration (too expensive).